# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in my word search program

Tags: c#

I don't understand what's going wrong here. Could someone explain please?

```
using System;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                int bobo = 0;
                string result = "";
                string bob;
                string search = Console.ReadLine();
                string words = Console.ReadLine();
                string first = words.Substring(0,1);
                string second = words.Substring(1,2);
                string third = words.Substring(2,3);
                for(int i = 0;i<searchc.Length;i++)
                {
                        bobo++;
                        bob = search.Substring(bobo,bobo+2);    
                        if(bob == first)
                        {
                                result += bob.ToUpper();
                        }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
}
```

The error message I see is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + length > this.length
Parameter name: length
  at System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Test.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: It's possible that some of your words aren't the length you are expecting them to be; for example, if your word was 1 letter long, word.Substring(0, 2) would fail because it would be extending beyond the length of the string - "ArgumentOutOfRangeException".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider doing a string.Split() for your 'words' object.

It would depend on what format the input would be, but for example:

words: 
'word1 word2 word3'

you could do the following:

```
var words = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If your 'words' is just a list of chars then, i would first make your code clearer by naming your strings better. It's very hard to understand what you are trying to do with the sample provided. But here is what I would do.

```
        var result = string.Empty;

        var search = Console.ReadLine();
        var words = Console.ReadLine();
        var first = words.Substring(0, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < search.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 > search.Length) break;
            var bob = search.Substring(i, i + 2);

            if (bob == first)
                result += bob.ToUpper();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you were searching a sentance for a list of words then try this:

```
        var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        var search = Console.ReadLine();
        var words = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (search.Contains(word))
                result.Append(string.Format("{0},", word));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gee, thanks a bunch! this is just something I threw together during lunch break so its not exactly perfect atleast I indented my code! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to help you bc your alg. looks flawed.

I would first add a check to make sure the length is > 2 and then the following logic should help.

Change bobo to i and update your for loop to `for(int i = 0;i<searchc.Length-1;i++)`

e.g.

```
bob = search.Substring(i,i+1);
```